# TXB0102 only translating in one direction

Tags: digital-logic

First time using the TXB0102 and I can only get it translating in one direction.  I'm using it to interface a 5V ATMEGA2560 hardware UART port to a 3.3V device with VOH 2.4-3.1V (TXB0102 table says VCCI x 0.65 so is well within spec) and VIH 2.0-3.6V.
I have VCCA @ 3.3V and VCCB @ 5V with OE controlled by an IO on VCCB and can get data from 5V>3V but not the other direction.  Screenshots are taken on matching A/B pins.  Any ideas?
[image: 5V to 3.3V logic conversion]

[image: 3.3V to 5V logic conversion]

[image: Portion of schematic]

Comment: Can you show your circuit schematic? If we take your description at face value, then you've connected your 3.3V IO to the 5V supply side and the 5.0V IO to the 3.3V supply side. I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: Edited to add schematic.  Labelled nets go to the ATMEGA direct to pins without any components attached.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Are you sure OE is asserted at the right times? ATMEGA2560 isn't misconfigured to drive the non-functioning signal as an output? No pull-up or pull-down resistors?

Comment: In my tests I have left OE high for the duration of the test and the A2/B2 is working fine so OE is clearly being asserted.  After the initial test didn't work as expected I loaded up code that only defines the OE and SHDN pins as outputs, sets them high then defines only UART3 and UART2 (Connected to console) and relays incoming bytes between them thus ruling out any other code that could be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some issues with TXB0106 which works the same way as TXB0102 (I think). When keeping VCCB powered and cycling VCCA together with OE, the TXB froze with the outputs stuck somewhere in between GND and VCC. Our solution to this was to actively push the datalines from the CPU side, to high before setting them to the correct function.

You could try and set a stiff pulldown on the OE pin so the MCU won't trigger the output enable during reset.

Comment: I believe they are the same with the exception of the amount of circuits but I don't think that's the issue because it's working in the 5V -> 3V direction OK when OE is pulled, it is just the reverse that is not working.